# How to calculate timedeltas in python with django right?

Tags: javascript, python, django, datetime, datepicker

I am stuck with my time tracking app. I am using django with python 3.
At this time, I am calculating a time difference between 2 datetime.datetime objects, which I am combining with datetime.combine.

This is my code:

```
dt_start = datetime.combine(self.entry_date, self.entry_start_time)
dt_end = datetime.combine(self.entry_date, self.entry_end_time)
time_delta = dt_end - dt_start
time_delta = time_delta - timedelta(hours=t_daily.hour,minutes=t_daily.minute)
self.entry_time_delta = int(time_delta.total_seconds() // 60)
profile.overtime = + self.entry_time_delta
profile.save()
```

As you see, I am first combining the entry_date with the entry_start_time to get a datetime.datetime object. Then I am combining the entry_date with the entry_end_time to get another datetime.datetime object. Unfortunatly, it is not possible to subtract 2 datetime.time objects.

With my new datetime.timedelta object, I can subtract the daily working time (stored in a "profile" class) converted to a timedelta object and save the delta in the profile's "overtime".

This is really horrible for me! Later I want to write a form with a timepicker/datepicker Javascript and I don't know, if I am running into problems, because now the model's entry_start_time and entry_end_time is a "models.TimeField" object. All the Javascript code for timepickers and datepickers I saw, expected a textfield in the form.

So is there any best practise for calculating times in django/python, if I want to use timepicker/datepickers later on?

Thank you all in advance!

Edit:

Here are my classes:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    entry_date = models.DateField('entry date')
    entry_start_time = models.TimeField('start time')
    entry_end_time = models.TimeField('end time')
    entry_vacation = models.BooleanField('took vacation', default=False)
    entry_overhours = models.BooleanField('took overhours', default=False)
    entry_time_delta = models.IntegerField('time difference today', editable=False)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.entry_date)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ''' Get work_time from Profile'''
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user_id=self.user_id)
    if profile.daily_work_time is not None:
        t_daily = profile.daily_work_time
    ''' On save, calculate TimeDelta'''
    if self.entry_vacation is True and self.entry_overhours is False:
        self.entry_start_time = 0
        self.entry_end_time = 0
        self.entry_time_delta = 0
        profile.actual_vacation_days = - 1
        profile.save()
        return super(Entry, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.entry_overhours is True and self.entry_vacation is False:
        self.entry_start_time = 0
        self.entry_end_time = 0
        self.entry_time_delta = 0 - timedelta(hours=t_daily.hour, minutes=t_daily.minute)
        self.entry_time_delta = int(time_delta.total_seconds() // 60)
        profile.overtime = + self.entry_time_delta
        profile.save()
        return super(Entry, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if not self.entry_time_delta:
        dt_start = datetime.combine(self.entry_date, self.entry_start_time)
        dt_end = datetime.combine(self.entry_date, self.entry_end_time)
        time_delta = dt_end - dt_start
        time_delta = time_delta - timedelta(hours=t_daily.hour, minutes=t_daily.minute)
        self.entry_time_delta = int(time_delta.total_seconds() // 60)
        profile.overtime = + self.entry_time_delta
        profile.save()
        return super(Entry, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Meta:
    unique_together = ("entry_date", "user_id")


class Profile(models.Model):
    yearly_vacation_days = models.IntegerField('yearly vacation days')
    actual_vacation_days = models.IntegerField('actual vacation days')
    daily_work_time = models.TimeField('daily work time')
    overtime = models.IntegerField('overall time')
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Comment: It's not really clear what the *exact* problem you are trying to solve is - can you be more specific?

Comment: I want to avoid all this datetime.combine thing just to get objects, that can be subtracted via datetime.timedelta. I am sure, there is a better way to calculate these deltas (e.g. timestamps) but I don't know, which is the best practise ( or at least a better practise).

Comment: What prevents your models having an entry_datetime rather than a separate date and time field?

Comment: I want to show the user a list of all days he/she saved. So I am using the entry_date in a view to link it to the details of this day. Additionally, I can ensure that there are no duplicate entries for one day (with "unique_together").

Comment: What happens if someone works over midnight?

Comment: Also, I'm still not sure what the problem is. You say "All the Javascript code for timepickers and datepickers I saw, expected a textfield in the form." - but Django provides excellent support for form validation/transformation. Have you looked into that? What is specific problem with that?

Comment: If someone works over midnight, he/she has to finish the first day with an end_time of 24:00 and add the rest to the next day. Like someone worked from yesterday 7 am to 2 am the next day, I would say: day 1 7 am to 24:00 and 00:00 to 2 am.

Comment: I am new to Javascript and the jquery-ui datepickers I saw, expected a textfield in the form. But the django-model says it is a "models.TimeField". Now, if I use the model.Form, does django parse the model.TimeField (in HTML) to a TextField?

Comment: You'll need to add some code to the form to make it do a sensible conversion, but it's not too hard to do. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields for more info.

Comment: Thank you for that hint! But am I on the right way to calculate these timedeltas? Should I use timestamps or parsing the seconds of the entries to integers?